# Entity Framework - how not to add inherited class to the db

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have base class

```
public class MenuItem
{
        [Key]
        public Guid MenuItemID { get; set; }

        public int MenuType { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsActive { get; set; }
        public String Details { get; set; }
}
```

and an inherited class

```
public class MenuItem_URL : MenuItem
{
        public String StartURL { get; set; }
        public Boolean ChangePageEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

I use Entity Framework code-first.

Now I want to store in DB `MenuItem` rows but NOT `MenuItem_URL`.

I add to context

```
public DbSet<MenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
```

The problem is that in my database creates strange table for `MenuItem`

```
[MenuItemID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[MenuType] [int] NOT NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
[Details] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[StartURL] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[ChangePageEnabled] [bit] NULL
```

Why does Entity Framework add `StartURL` and `ChangePageEnabled` columns? And how to tell him not to? I want to store only base `MenuItem` objects without any additional data from inherited objects

Comment: Have you tried `NotMapped`?

Comment: I don't understand. What is `'NotMapped'`?

Comment: Are you sure your DbSet is of type MenuItem and not MenuItem_URL ?Also,have you added another DbSet of type MenuItem_URL  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to tell EF to ignore a property or the whole class by using the `NotMapped` attribute

```
[NotMapped]
public class MenuItem_URL : MenuItem  {
    public String StartURL { get; set; }
    public Boolean ChangePageEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

or by using the `Ignore<T>()` method in the fluent configuration.

```
public class MYContext : DbContext {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Ignore<MenuItem_URL>();
    }

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell Entity Framework that it doesn't need to store the properties.

```
public class MenuItem_URL : MenuItem
{
    [NotMapped]
    public String StartURL { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Boolean ChangePageEnabled { get; set; }
}
```